# Encode categorial features in given order with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I need to encode categorial features in my dataset. I want them to be ordered, so that 'low' comes to 0 and 'vhigh' comes to 3.
I tried using label encoder from preprocessing:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['low', 'med', 'high', 'vhigh'])
ar = le.transform(df[df["buying"] == 'low']["buying"])
```

Unfortunately features were not ordered: 4th line returns array of ones, and I want an array of zeros.

I tried to create another encoder that maps numbers to numbers I want. But it seems to have just no result.

```
other_le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
other_le.fit([1, 2, 0, 3])
other_le.transform(ar)
```

Last line returns ones again.

How to keep an order on categorial features in the shortest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LabelEncoder` will sort your features according to the output of Python's builtin `sorted()` function, which in this case will order them alphabetically. It would not be hard to write your own function to label these in a way that maintains the order you're looking for:

```
def label( array ):
    labels = ['low', 'med', 'high', 'vhigh']
    return map( labels.index, array )
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `factorize` function from pandas. 
 It encodes values based on sequence i.e. if low is first, it gets encoded as 0,  medium gets 1 and so on.

```
import pandas as pd
myli = ['low','medium','high','very_high']
pd.factorize(myli)[0]

# output
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```